# How do I set VLC up to stream a local camera to localhost, so another app can pick it up as if it is an IP Camera?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, streaming

I am using VisualPlace, for planing manual PnP layouts and also when manually laying out SMD on a PCB.

VisualPlace allows for streamed IP cameras to be used to view the PCB while working on the PCB.

I have a USB "snake" camera, mounted on the manual PnP machine, to connect to my Jesse based Acer Aspire One.  So I am hoping to view that USB camera (somehow) by streaming using VLC, so VisualPlace can pick the stream off the localhost.

I cannot connect VisualPlace directly to the internal camera (/dev/video0), so I need to stream that camera.  That is, VisualPlace, by design, does not have the option for directly connecting to internal cameras.

I am using an old Acer Aspire One since it's on hand, running Jesse 8, and I have VLC running on that machine.  As I am using Jesse, and will continue to regardless, I have found trying to install any other camera streaming option than VLC appears a struggle, given the archiving of repositories, various problems with dependencies etc. So, presently, it's down to whether VLC can work, as if, an IP camera.

So far, while it appears to have been a straightforward problem to set VLC up to stream capture sources, to talk VLC to VLC.  However, I am not fully over the whole IP camera streaming issue, and it isn't apparent that, in the first place, I can set up VLC to stream as if it were an IP camera.

The question is; therefore, if there were a setup for VLC to stream as if it were an IP camera to localhost (or any host really), what would the setup be? Does this actually require a plugin for VLC?